# Kivy Python ThreeLineIconListItem

Tags: kivymd

I have created a list as described below. How can I handle interaction with each list item so that the selected book can be "reserved". I did not find any documentation about interactions with `ThreeLineIconListItem` based lists.

Any help is appreciated

```
    for book in books:
        self.ids.list.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon=icons[3])
                                 )

        self.ids.list.add_widget(ThreeLineIconListItem(text=f"{str(book[0])}",
                                                       secondary_text=f"{str(book[1])}",
                                                       tertiary_text=f"{str(book[2])}"
                                                       )
                                 )
```

Comment: Hi  can anybody help. Really stuck and dont know where to go being new to Kivy and Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should add the **IconLeftWidget** to ThreeLineIconListItem and then you can add
the ThreeLineIconListItem to your **list**.

```
for book in books:
    my_icon_list = ThreeLineIconListItem(
                          text=f"{str(book[0])}",
                          secondary_text=f"{str(book[1])}",
                          tertiary_text=f"{str(book[2])}")
    my_icon_list.add_widget(IconLeftWidget(icon=icons[3])
    self.ids.list.add_widget(my_icon_list)
```